# JUnit 0 Tests found

Tags: java, testing, junit

I want to write a simple Testclass where I add two numbers:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class ttest {

  private final ttest tT = new ttest();

  public int add(int one, int two) {
    return one + two;
  }

  @Test
  public void eq() {
    int result = tT.add(1, 2);
    assertEquals(result, 3);
    assertTrue(result == 3);
  }
}
```

It compiles correctly but if I run the Test in console it says:

```
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔
[         2 containers found      ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 tests found           ]
```

It found all "containers" but not the Testcase to add the numbers.
(I start the Test run with a script from my course so the problem has to be in the .java)

The script I run it with in console is:

```
javac --class-path="junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar" ttest*.java
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar --class-path="." --scan-class-path
```

Comment: What is `@Test`'s fully qualified class name (in other words - what are you importing for `@Test`)?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so, you have to annotate your test with spring boot  test annotation, like `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`. If you are not using spring boot, then I guess you still need to set the `@RunWith` annotation

Comment: @Mureinik I imported the Annotation Type "Test" by org.junit.jupiter.api.*; (I made a mistake not to copy the first import line to Stack Overflow)

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I'm not using Spring Boot. In class we didn't use @ RunWith Annotation aswell and our tests worked there. So I think this won't be the problem?

Comment: @fid, could you tell how you invoke/run junit then?

Comment: @abc the lecturer gave out a jarfile "junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar". Then took it to the classpath. Hope that's what you asked for.

Comment: @fid, I'm not sure either. You run it through IDE, Maven, Gradle, somewhat else? I mean to get your second snipet from you question you had to do something - like run some script, press button in IDE, etc.

Comment: @fid can you add the script?

Comment: The script: javac --class-path="junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar" ttest*.java
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar --class-path="." --scan-class-path

Comment: @fid please edit question and post this "script" for question completness, as part of question (just add another code snippet). Otherwise someone with same issue might not classify it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can be run for instance by renaming class to `TTest`.

According to official docs: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M5/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

> -n, --include-classname  Provide a regular expression to include only classes whose fully qualified names match.
> To avoid loading classes unnecessarily, the default pattern only
> includes class names that end with "Test" or "Tests". When this option
> is repeated, all patterns will be combined using OR semantics.
> (default: ^.*Tests?$)

So simply put your class was not matching default pattern and thus was not picked up by framework.